# Can I "roll back" to the PDF without OCR?

Tags: pdf, scanning, ocr, abbyy

I'm using Automator in combination with Abbys Finereader to watch a Folder for new scanned PDF documents. The Finereader OCRs the Document and exports it to a new PDF in the same Folder. For a month now I've used the export Setting "text over page image". The User Guides explanation of this setting is:

> This option saves the background and pictures of the original document
>   and places the recognized text over them. Usually, a PDF file saved
>   using this option requires more disk space than a file that has been
>   saved with the Text and pictures only option enabled. The resulting
>   PDF document is fully searchable. In some cases, the appearance of the
>   resulting document may slightly differ from the original.

The problem is that some of the PDFs that have been scanned and "OCRed" have many wrong characters in it but I just found out about this failure.

Is it in any way possible to "roll back" to the Version without the OCR?
I tried to export the PDF as an TIFF File, but in there are also the wrong characters...

Any ideas?

Comment: The only way I know is to restore the original document.  it sounds like you don't have the original document.

Comment: Jeah, I don't have the original document..

Answer (score 0):

Since you wrote that you chose "text over page image", you still should have the original scanned images in your PDF files. 
To get it back: 
If you have Adobe Acrobat there is the option to Save As > Image > JPG, TIFF, etc.
Otherwise use a free pdf editor e.g. PDF-XChange Viewer and in the File menu choose Export > Export to Image... and choose your image format e.g. TIFF. 
In this way, I am able to revert my OCRed PDF documents (text + image) back to the originally scanned images.

You wrote that you tried to export them back to images (in Finereader?) and the resulting images still contained "wrong characters". It looks like you did not chose "text over page image" but an option that does not keep the scanned image but rebuilds its layout with the OCRed text (Adobe Acrobat calls this ClearScan). This function rebuilds the layout of the scan as close as possible with the OCRed text in the most suitable fond and does not keep the scanned image in the PDF.